# bash: integer * float multiplication

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a simple multiplication between int and float numbers in bash:

```
int='10'
float='0.001'

# should give 0.01
multip=$(( float*int ))
```

produces error

```
bash: 0.001 : erreur de syntaxe : opérateur arithmétique non valable (le symbole erroné est « .001 »)
```

what should be fixed ?

Comment: You might want to use `bc`: `bc <<< "$int * $float"` prints `.010`.

Comment: You need a language which can do fractional arithmetic. `bc`, or `awk`, or `zsh` for instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash doesn't support floats. Use an external program for that, e.g. `bc`.

```
int=10
float=0.001
multip=$(bc <<< "$int * $float")
```

Note that `bc` doesn't output the leading 0 in `0.01`, so you need to add some string processing, e.g.

```
multip=${multip/#./0.} # Insert 0 before the leading dot.
```

To remove the trailing zeros, you can similarly

```
shopt -s extglob      # Recognise the +(...) construct.
multip=${multip%+(0)} # Remove the trailing zeros.
```

Comment: great ! just a quick question, eventually it produces something like 0.010. So the last zero should be notmally omitted ... :-)